# How to add results from loop into an outside variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I have a quiz on a page where the user can input a number of drinks, and depending on the number it will show a different result.

There is a page with drink selection, and when the user selects a drink I use jQuery to add a data attribute of `drink-calculate='yes'`

The HTML markup for their selected drinks looks like this -

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column choices">
    <div class="selection-box" data-drink-name="Beer (341 ml) 5% alcohol" data-calculate="yes">
        <div>
            <span class="counter-btn decrease me-2" role="button" data-inc="-1">
                -
            </span>
            <div class="output me-2">3</div>
            <span class="counter-btn increase" role="button" data-inc="1">
                +
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="selection-box" data-drink-name="Glass of Wine (5 oz pour/ 142 ml) 12% alcohol" data-calculate="yes">
        <div>
            <span class="counter-btn decrease me-2" role="button" data-inc="-1">
                -
            </span>
            <div class="output me-2">4</div>
            <span class="counter-btn increase" role="button" data-inc="1">
                +
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="quiz-button">
    <span class="btn btn-primary mt-4" id="calculate">Calculate</span>
</div>
```

I have a function set up in jQuery so that when `#calculate` is clicked it loops through each `.selection-box` div, and there is a conditional so that if `data-calculate="yes"` then it will loop through each `.counter .output` (this is where the number of drinks is) and will return a total.

I want to get this total number, and run it through a function that looks like this -

```
const calculate = (value) => {
    let result = 'no result'
    if (value === 0) {
        result = 'first-result'
    } else if (value >= 1 && value < 3) {
        result = 'second-result'
    } else if (value >= 3 && value < 7) {
        result = 'third-result'
    } else if (value >= 7) {
        result = 'fourth-result'
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the code I have to get that total number -

```
$("#calculate").click(function (event) {
    $("#question2").addClass('d-none')
    $('#question2 .choices > .selection-box').each(function () {
        let totalDrinks = 0;
        if (this.dataset.calculate === 'yes') {
            $(this).find('.counter .output').each(function () {
                totalDrinks = this.innerText++;
                return totalDrinks;
            })
        }
        calculate(totalDrinks);
        if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'first-result') {
            $("#results > .results-1").removeClass('d-none')
        } else if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'second-result') {
            $("#results > .results-2").removeClass('d-none')
        } else if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'third-result') {
            $("#results > .results-3").removeClass('d-none')
        } else if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'fourth-result'); {
            $("#results > .results-4").removeClass('d-none')
        }
    })
    $("#results").removeClass('d-none')
})
```

and for context, this is the HTML markup for the results

```
<div class="step-results d-none" id="results" data-slide="4">
    <div class="results-1 d-none">
        Result 1
    </div>
    <div class="results-2 d-none">
        Result 2
    </div>
    <div class="results-3 d-none">
        Result 3
    </div>
    <div class="results-4 d-none">
        Result 4
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the way I have the code set up inside the loop it runs the `calculate()` function for each number. I want it to calculate a total number, then run this total number through the `calculate()` function.

If I take it out of the loop then I cannot access the total number that is calculated.

Right now it runs the `calculate()` function for each drink. So if there is a drink that is 1, and a drink that is 4, it runs `calculate(1)` (which will show result 1), and `calculate(4)` (which shows result 2). I need it to add 1+4 and run `calculate(5)`

Comment: Did you mean `data-calculate="yes"`?

Comment: What specifically isn't working in the code shown?  When you step through this code in a debugger, which operation is failing?

Comment: `return totalDrinks` is unnecessary. The return value of the `.each()` callback is only used to determine if the loop should stop; it breaks out of the loop when the return value is `false`.

Comment: @David the problem is that it is running the calculate() function for each value. So if there is a drink that is 1, and a drink that is 4, it calculates 1 (which will show result 1), and calculates 4 (which shows result 2). I need it to add 1+4 and run calculate(5)

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of `totalDrinks` and the call to `calculate()` outside the first `.each()` loop.

You need to add to `totalDrinks` in the loop, not reassign it from each `innerText`.

```
$("#calculate").click(function(event) {
  $("#question2").addClass('d-none')
  let totalDrinks = 0;
  $('#question2 .choices > .selection-box').each(function() {
    if (this.dataset.calculate === 'yes') {
      $(this).find('.counter .output').each(function() {
        totalDrinks += this.innerText;
      })
    }
  })
  calculate(totalDrinks);
  if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'first-result') {
    $("#results > .results-1").removeClass('d-none')
  } else if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'second-result') {
    $("#results > .results-2").removeClass('d-none')
  } else if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'third-result') {
    $("#results > .results-3").removeClass('d-none')
  } else if (calculate(totalDrinks) === 'fourth-result'); {
    $("#results > .results-4").removeClass('d-none')
  }
  $("#results").removeClass('d-none')
})
```